# Flutter dropdown menu with ListTiles and row of Buttons

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to build out a custom dropdown menu that looks like this:

[image: Goal Dropdown UI]

I've managed to implement the `ListTiles` and `Row` of `Buttons` without the dropdown, but I'm not sure how to nest all of that within a dropdown menu class. This is what I've got so far:

[image: Current Dropdown UI]

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                onTap: () {},
                leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[0]),
                title: Text('All Circles'),
              ),
              Divider(color: Colors.grey.shade400, indent: 72.0, height: 1.0),
              ListTile(
                onTap: () {},
                leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[1]),
                title: Text('Pickup'),
              ),
              Divider(color: Colors.grey.shade400, indent: 72.0, height: 1.0),
              ListTile(
                onTap: () {},
                leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[2]),
                title: Text('Kappa Delta'),
              ),
              Divider(color: Colors.grey.shade400, indent: 72.0, height: 1.0),
              ListTile(
                onTap: () {},
                leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[3]),
                title: Text('Ok Boomer'),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Join a Circle"),
                    color: Color(0xffb74093),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Create a Circle"),
                    color: Colors.red,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can use `ListTile` after the `items:` directly. 
If you did run the code above, you're getting errors.
it needs to return `DropdownMenuItem` instead of `ListTile` directly

```
return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
    value: value,
    child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[3]),
        Text(value)
    ],
));
```

I think the above code would be relatively correct.

Comment: `Row` is repeating with value

Answer (score -2):

this is very simple first create a drop-down menu widget and then give your widget to a drop-down menu item

like this

give value to each drop-down item according to your objects array

```
DropdownButton<String>(
value: dropdownValue,
icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
iconSize: 24,
elevation: 16,
style: TextStyle(
  color: Colors.deepPurple
),
underline: Container(
  height: 2,
  color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
),
onChanged: (String newValue) {
  setState(() {
    dropdownValue = newValue;
  });
},
items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return ListTile(
            onTap: () {},
            leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[0]),
            title: Text(value),
          );
  })
  .toList(),
```

);

Comment: How can a Map<DropDownMenuItem> have Elements of ListTile ?! Do you run your code?